# problem fiting my dataset into my model python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a problem fitting my dataset into my model. I do not know what this error represent and surely not how to fix it. thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
dataset
```

[image: dataset desciption on Jupiter]

```
X=dataset.iloc[:,3:13].values
Y=dataset.iloc[:,13].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
lableencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = lableencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

ct = ColumnTransformer([('ohe', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype = str)
X = X[:, 1:]

classifier.add(Dense(units = 6,kernel_initializer = 'uniform',activation ='relu',input_dim = 11))

classifier.add(Dense(units = 6,kernel_initializer = 'uniform',activation ='relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(units= 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform',activation = 'sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crssentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# fit our dataset to our module.
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

Error:
[image: Error picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well error message is pretty clear. The loss function should be `binary_crossentropy` not `binary_crssentropy`

Comment: what loss function are you talking about? where do I redefine it?

Comment: `classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crssentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])`

Comment: omg I need to get some sleep. that's fixed my code!